# level=fatal msg="ipset [destroy] failed: ipset v6.29: Set cannot be destroyed: it is in use by a kernel component\n: exit status 1"

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, weave, kubeadm

- Basic Information:

  1. System:

     ```
     # cat /proc/version

     Linux version 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 23:06:41 UTC 2016
     ```
  2. Kubeadm Version:

     ```
     # kubeadm version

     kubeadm version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6+", GitVersion:"v1.6.0-alpha.0.2074+a092d8e0f95f52", GitCommit:"a092d8e0f95f5200f7ae2cba45c75ab42da36537", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-13T17:03:18Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
     ```
  3. Kubectl Version

     ```
     # kubectl version

     Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.1", GitCommit:"82450d03cb057bab0950214ef122b67c83fb11df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-14T00:57:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
     Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.1", GitCommit:"82450d03cb057bab0950214ef122b67c83fb11df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-14T00:52:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
     ```
  4. Docker Version

     ```
     # docker version

     Client:
      Version:      1.12.5
      API version:  1.24
      Go version:   go1.6.4
      Git commit:   7392c3b
      Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
      OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

     Server:
      Version:      1.12.5
      API version:  1.24
      Go version:   go1.6.4
      Git commit:   7392c3b
      Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
      OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
     ```
  5. Weave Images

     ```
     REPOSITORY                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
     weaveworks/weave-npc                                     1.8.2               c91ef3f4642b        4 weeks ago         68.77 MB
     weaveworks/weave-kube                                    1.8.2               a4740ae55aae        4 weeks ago         166.7 MB
     ```
- Problem

  I am deploying k8s by using kubeadm. It is strange that,  at **First Time**  weave works fine with kube-dns on a new VM, **BUT**, after reset the kubeadm and re-init, weave CAN NOT work anymore.

  - Kubectl Get Pods

    ```
    [root@192-168-1-177 pod_network]# kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
    NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
    kube-system   dummy-2088944543-tdxck                         1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   etcd-192-168-1-177.master                      1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   kube-apiserver-192-168-1-177.master            1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   kube-controller-manager-192-168-1-177.master   1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   kube-discovery-1769846148-87pgm                1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   kube-dns-2924299975-82sb6                      4/4       Running            0          59m       10.32.0.2       192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   kube-proxy-8xprh                               1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   kube-scheduler-192-168-1-177.master            1/1       Running            0          59m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    kube-system   weave-net-ssqtd                                1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   16         58m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
    ```
  - Kubectl Logs

    ```
      # kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep weave-net | awk '{print $2}') -n kube-system weave-npc

      time="2017-01-09T11:11:17Z" level=info msg="Starting Weaveworks NPC 1.8.2" 
      time="2017-01-09T11:11:17Z" level=info msg="Serving /metrics on :6781" 
      Mon Jan  9 11:11:17 2017 <5> ulogd.c:843 building new pluginstance stack: 'log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,pcap1:PCAP'
      time="2017-01-09T11:11:17Z" level=fatal msg="ipset [destroy] failed: ipset v6.29: Set cannot be destroyed: it is in use by a kernel component\n: exit status 1"
    ```
- Basic Operation

  - Kubeadm Init

    ```
    kubeadm init --api-advertise-addresses 192.168.1.177 --use-kubernetes-version v1.5.1
    ```
  - Apply Weave

    ```
    kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube
    ```
  - Kubeadm Reset

    ```
    kubeadm reset
    docker rm `docker ps -a -q`
    find /var/lib/kubelet | xargs -n 1 findmnt -n -t tmpfs -o TARGET -T | uniq | xargs -r umount -v
    rm -r -f /etc/kubernetes /var/lib/kubelet /var/lib/etcd
    ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own questions just by **REBOOT** my VM machine.

Before the reboot:

- Ipset List

  ```
  # ipset list

  Name: weave-k?Z;25^M}|1s7P3|H9i;*;MhG
  Type: hash:ip
  Revision: 1
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
  Size in memory: 16528
  References: 0
  Members:

  Name: weave-iuZcey(5DeXbzgRFs8Szo]<@p
  Type: hash:ip
  Revision: 1
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
  Size in memory: 16528
  References: 0
  Members:

  Name: weave-#Of<X6ofOD9U?jkdAmmuY.VL(
  Type: hash:ip
  Revision: 1
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
  Size in memory: 16528
  References: 0
  Members:

  Name: felix-calico-hosts-4
  Type: hash:ip
  Revision: 1
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 1048576
  Size in memory: 16528
  References: 1
  Members:

  Name: felix-all-ipam-pools
  Type: hash:net
  Revision: 3
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 1048576
  Size in memory: 16784
  References: 1
  Members:

  Name: felix-masq-ipam-pools
  Type: hash:net
  Revision: 3
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 1048576
  Size in memory: 16784
  References: 1
  Members:
  ```
- Ipset Destroy

  ```
  # ipset destroy

  ipset v6.19: Set cannot be destroyed: it is in use by a kernel component
  ```

After the reboot:

- Ipset List

  ```
  # ipset list

  Name: weave-iuZcey(5DeXbzgRFs8Szo]<@p
  Type: hash:ip
  Revision: 1
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
  Size in memory: 16544
  References: 1
  Members:
  10.32.0.2

  Name: weave-k?Z;25^M}|1s7P3|H9i;*;MhG
  Type: hash:ip
  Revision: 1
  Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
  Size in memory: 16528
  References: 1
  Members:
  ```

And everything is OK.

- Kubectl Get Pods

  ```
  # kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces

  NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
  default       busybox                                        1/1       Running   0          6s        10.44.0.1       192-168-1-178.node
  kube-system   dummy-2088944543-05kj3                         1/1       Running   0          19m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   etcd-192-168-1-177.master                      1/1       Running   0          18m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   kube-apiserver-192-168-1-177.master            1/1       Running   0          18m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   kube-controller-manager-192-168-1-177.master   1/1       Running   0          17m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   kube-discovery-1769846148-3t242                1/1       Running   0          19m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   kube-dns-2924299975-6bv1x                      4/4       Running   0          19m       10.32.0.2       192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   kube-proxy-4jqzb                               1/1       Running   0          19m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   kube-proxy-kxkxm                               1/1       Running   0          10m       192.168.1.178   192-168-1-178.node
  kube-system   kube-scheduler-192-168-1-177.master            1/1       Running   0          18m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  kube-system   weave-net-jgwwt                                2/2       Running   0          10m       192.168.1.178   192-168-1-178.node
  kube-system   weave-net-s4w7w                                2/2       Running   0          17m       192.168.1.177   192-168-1-177.master
  ```